# get title from Zotero item

Tags: rust, rust-rocket

Still very new to Rust, trying to understand how to extract the `title` of a `JournalArticle` using the [Zotero crate](https://docs.rs/zotero/latest/zotero/).

I've got this, and can confirm the item is retrieved successfully:

```rust
let zc = ZoteroCredentials::new();
let z = ZoteroInit::set_user(&zc.api_id, &zc.api_key);
let item = z.get_item(item_id, None).unwrap();
```

From here, I see that an `item.data` is an `ItemType`, specifically a [JournalArticleData](https://docs.rs/zotero/latest/zotero/data_structure/item/struct.JournalArticleData.html).  But I'm fundamentally not quite understanding how to either a) serialize this to JSON, or b) access `.title` as a property.

For context, this would be the result of a [Rocket](https://rocket.rs/) `GET` route.

Any help would much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the part you're missing is how to use pattern matching on an enum. I'm not familiar with `zotero` so this is all based on the docs, with verbose type annotations to be explicit about what I think I'm doing:

```rust
use zotero::data_structure::item::{Item, ItemType, JournalArticleData};

let item: Item = z.get_item(item_id, None).unwrap();

// Now we must extract the JournalArticle from the ItemType, which is an enum
// and therefore requires pattern matching.
let article: JournalArticleData = match item.data {
    ItemType::JournalArticle(a) => a,
    something_else => todo!("handle wrong type of item"),
}

let title: String = article.title;
```

(The `match` could also be written as an `if let` just as well.)

You could also use pattern matching to go through the entire structure, rather than only the enum which requires it:

```rust
match z.get_item(item_id, None).unwrap() {
    Item {
        data: ItemType::JournalArticle(JournalArticleData {
            title,
            ..
        }),
        ..
    } => {
        // Use the `title` variable here
    },
    something_else => todo!("handle wrong type of item"),
}
```

Comment: Many thanks!  Appreciate the explanation and suggestion for more deep pattern matching.  It looks as though the `JournalArticleData` struct has a `Vec<Creator>` when parsing the JSON from the API, which can fail if those don't have `firstName` included.  But that's a problem for another day!  Thanks again.